# Suddenly my web-api project can't find references to System.Web.Mvc, compiles fine but runtime error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Suddenly my web-api project has stopped being able to run (though it compiles fine). It now says that it cannot find System.Web.Mvc in System.Web. Looking at the app history I noticed that the project file changed the reference from Prviate=True to private = False and removing the property processorArchitecture=MSIL.

What could have caused this and why is it breaking my runtime?

Here is a relavent section of my csproj file that changed.
Original:

```
  <Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
```

New:

```
   <Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">   <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
     </Reference>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like `System.Web.Mvc.dll` is missing from your application's `bin` directory.

Select the reference to `System.Web.Mvc` in Solution Explorer and in the Properties pane choose "Copy Local: True". Clean and Rebuild and that should do it.

Comment: that did the trick, I wonder why that changed all of a sudden.

Comment: This just happened to me too.  Copy Local will sort but why did it do it all of a sudden?  Any implications to a web deploy by setting the Copy Local?

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered the same thing - a project that had compiled suddenly seemed to be missing `System.Web.Mvc.dll`.

After adding the reference (from `Assemblies/Extensions`) and comparing the .csproj file with the previous version, I can see that `System.Web.Mvc.dll` has obviously been upgraded on my machine from `3.0.0.0` to `3.0.0.1` - possibly during a Windows Update.

So check version that is specified in you .csproj file, and then compare it to what is available in `Assemblies/Extensions` - it may be that a minor version increment is the cause of the problem.